# Woocommerce remove variations table (hook, action)

Tags: woocommerce, hook

I want to remove a variations section from single product in woocommerce.

On this links there are various sections on the single product page which you can enhance or remove.
https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/#

I have not found anywhere where the dropdown variations table or form can be removed using remove_action.

I would like to remove Ttitle of variation and the dropdown with options using command in example
Example:
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working,but does not seem to be right.

```
<style>
    div.woocommerce-variation-price, table.variations { display:none; }
</style>
```